# Select an element in Appium

Tags: appium

In this activity, I have 5 Text Views with same resource-id.

How can I select the first one with Java client Appium automation?

Is there any way to use resource-id and index combination.

I expect a **non xpath strategy** if available to select that.

[image: UI Automator view]

Comment: any specific reason not to use Xpath? If you are not using absolute path, its far more advantageous. Dont you think so?

Comment: I read that **xpath** strategy takes more resources that **id** strategy

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the Linear layout 1st.
2. Then using `<iList> iWebElement`  get all the elemants which have id
   name as `Normal_view`
3. After that you will be getting a list of items of `Text Views.`
4. Then access what ever the element you want using its index number.

below is a sample ,but in c#

```
 IList<IWebElement> sidemenuList = elm2.Modules.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            sidemenuList[4].Click();
```

Comment: Can you post in Java if possible. Anyway, there is no tag called **li** in question

Comment: yeah so add (By.class("Android.widget.textview"));

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are looking for, will you need to use all 5 textViews in your tests or will you only need the 3rd and never use others?

For the former create a list of webElements, then iterate through the list depending on which element you need at the moment. The syntax is pretty easy:

```
List<WebElement> elementsList = driver.findElements("your locator strategy")
elementsList.get(2).click; //this will click on the highlighted element from your screenshot
```

For the latter:
1. use either an xpath or UiAutomator locator (both have options to get to a specific element) 
2. use page factory and @FindBys annotation to get a chained locator.
3. if the element you're looking for has a unique id - then you can locate it with id, else - don't. If you absolutely want to use id locators, then ask your developers to add unique ids to all elements that you need